# Подскажите MS SQL Server совместимые MDM (Master data management) системы

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Знаю, что у MS SQL Server есть родной Master Data Services.

Есть ли еще какие-нибудь MDM для MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Talend MDM
2. Informatica MDM
3. Pentaho MDM
4. TIBCO MDM

Вроде есть что-то у RedHat, на основе JBoss...

Но прямой коннект к БД есть вроде только у Informatica MDM, остальные через JDBC подключаются.

iluxa1810, дело в том, что при физическом копировании справочника, теряется связь с с источником, например: есть репозиторий исходного кода. Его правят 3 разработчика. Пришел четвертый сделал copy с репозитория и стал тоже править. В результате у трех разрабов все хорошо, они делали checkout&change&commit, а у четвертого швах. Если связи не прописаны, если логика не простроена, то изменения не будут синхронизированы.

Тип БД здесь имеет "второстепенное" значение. Главное чтобы был коннект к ней, а в вашем случае ODBC позволит подключиться к БД Access, но работать будет не шибко быстро, как собственно и сама БД.

Comment: А есть такие MDM, которые способны держать в актуальном состоянии справочники БД Access?  Скажем, есть десяток файлов mdb, которые хранятся в одном месте. Копии этих файлов могут создаваться и копироваться в другие места. В Момент того, как происходят изменения в главном хранилише, эти изменения отражаются и на других файлах, которые были скопированы из главного хранилища.

Comment: Как-то так... А можете описать какие и как планировалось связывать системы, данные и прочее? Самое интересное почему используется БД Access...

Comment: Попытаюсь объяснить особо не вдаваясь в подробности тех. процесса: Есть N Access справочников, которые хранятся в одном месте(Пусть будет MainR). Для того, что бы использовать справочники в проекте их копируют в папку с проектом. Сейчас если возникает потребность добавить значение в справочник, то добавляют значение руками в MainR, потом этот справочник нужно заменить на актуальный в проектах, где он используется. Сейчас это никак не автоматизировано. И вот встает вопрос: Можно ли использовать готовую MDM систему, если можно то насколько придется замарачиваться с костылями

Comment: или проще сделать что-то свое? Грубо говоря получается такая картина. Есть справочник в MainR, и он используется в 10 проектах(Т.е есть 10 копий.). Может появится еще 1 проект, который будет использовать его и тогда система должна увидеть это. При изменении в MainR должна произойти синхронизация всех 11 справочников.

Comment: Использование access- это ограничение тех процесса.

Comment: В данном случае использование MDM не целесообразно. Зачастую при MDM используются описанные и подключенные к общей шине данных системы. В Вашем случае необходимо при каждом новом проекте "подключать" его в общую систему. Для Вас я бы автоматизировал создание тестовых сред и обновление боевых при изменении мастер-справочника. Понятно, что это можно сделать как при помощи батников, так и при помощи любой системы синхронизации данных, типа: btsync, syncthing и прочих. Также необходимо учесть насколько детерминированы изменения в справочниках? Возможно изменение мастер-справочника во время работы?

Comment: Могу добавлять значения в справочники, могут добавляться колонки, таблицы и тд. Изменение во время работы возможно.

Comment: Прошу прощения, что пропал. В Вашем случае действительно надо вводить; 1. Системы синхронизации справочников; 2. Скрипты по созданию девелоперских, тестовых и боевых сред; 3. Орг. указания, особенно если вы не один разработчик, как с этим всем работать.